# Help identify "blockart" game

Tags: identify-this-game

I remember a very good boardgame named "BLOCKART" that I played decades ago.

- It has a white board that has deep rectangle/hexagon slots.
- There are a lot of colorful rectangular cuboid tokens. Each can fill a slot.
- There are also some cute triangle prism tokens that can fill half of a slot.
- The tokens come in  4 colors - blue,green,yellow and red.
  I could purchase "addon" to add tokens of other colors.

Today, after searching for several years, I finally find its image in the internet.

However, that is it, there is no further information.

Please provide some description :-

- What is the manufacturer / distributor name?   What is its official website/page?
- If it does not violate this site, may you provide some locations I can buy it (online perhaps)?
- Are there any other similar game (board with deep slot + colorful rectangular cuboid tokens)?

[image]

All material are made of plastic.

Comment: Are you sure that it is a game?  Looking at it is seems more like a toy akin to Lego?

Comment: Are you sure this is actually a board game, with playable rules and conditions to win? This appears to be more like a design toy. If it is a board game, it is on-topic here, but if it is a toy then unfortunately it is off-topic sorry.

Comment: @Ken Herbert Ops, sorry, I may misremember it.  I always used it to play something like Othello or a custom landscape for some house-rule marble games. Which stackexchange should I ask about it?

Comment: Sorry but I really don't know where else you could ask about it here. I'm a bit surprised there isn't an SE site dedicated to toys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the product is actually called "BLOCK ART", and I believe it's made by Japanese company "Nichigan" (based on [this](https://global.rakuten.com/en/store/orange-baby/item/4975950170096/)).

I can't find a web page for Nichigan. Maybe someone that can read Japanese might have better luck? [Its logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMe9H.jpg).

It appears to be vintage, and it's probably no longer produced. Your best bet of finding one is probably through the vintage toy crowds.

Alternatives:

- [MARBLETICK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyQtL.jpg), by the same company
- [LAKESHORE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eIov.jpg), by the same company
- MARBLE ART, by the same company
- Hunt down this [Chinese knockoff(?)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/TY-490PCS-Embedded-Puzzle-Educational/dp/B00PQ2V772)
- [A more advanced wooden version](http://montys.toys/art-building-blocks-puzzle/)
- Build your own from Lego pieces
- Hire someone with a 3d printer to make one

Comment: Thank a lot. What googling (internet searching) technique you used to find the answer (especially "Nichigan")?

Comment: IIRC, I searched for `BLOCKART toy` and `"BLOCK ART" toy` (including quotes) and `"BLOCK ART" vintage toy`. I mostly used the image search feature. Remember that clicking on an image shows "related" images that are potentially more relevant. That led to the the main image of [this page](https://global.rakuten.com/en/store/orange-baby/item/4975950170096/), which mentions Nichigan. I wasn't confident in that name until I came across the listing for MABLE ART, which is clearly by Nichigan, and clearly by the same company.